# How to check if a value exists in jTable which I am trying to add?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

How to check in `jTable` the values I am trying to add from `jField` exists or not ? I am using `Vector<Object>` in `jTable`.

Comment: Iterate trough the values that populate your jtable?

Comment: agreed with @Jeroen Vannevel, JTables view can br filtered, column removed from view, XxxRenderer can modifyied real value stored in XxxTableModel

Comment: @Jeroen Vannevel, i think i'll do it your way! as i have commented in second Answer. Believe it's the same we talking about :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it.

```
public boolean existsInTable(JTable table, Object[] entry) {

    // Get row and column count
    int rowCount = table.getRowCount();
    int colCount = table.getColumnCount();

    // Get Current Table Entry
    String curEntry = "";
    for (Object o : entry) {
        String e = o.toString();
        curEntry = curEntry + " " + e;
    }

    // Check against all entries
    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
        String rowEntry = "";
        for (int j = 0; j < colCount; j++)
            rowEntry = rowEntry + " " + table.getValueAt(i, j).toString();
        if (rowEntry.equalsIgnoreCase(curEntry)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`JTable` does not provide this functionality.

`JTable` is only a visualization for a table model. Your data model should have the business functions you need, like telling you if an entry exists. You wrap the data model inside a `TableModel`that can be displayed by the `JTable`. You then only manipulate your data model. This is the place where a `contains` (or similar) method should exists. If your data model is a `Set` this is built in.

For convenience the data model and the `TableModel` can be the same object, sometimes it is appropriate. But just using a `Vector` is not a good idea. Sadly `JTable` has some convenience methods that allow this for static data.

Just build your own `TableModel` on top of `AbstractTableModel`. See the [JTable tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html).

Answer (score 1):

`Vector<Object>` makes a pretty poor model for a JTable!

You should write your own model class, perhaps derived from javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel, something like

```
public class FooModel extends javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel {

  // AbstractTableModel
  public int getRowCount() { //TBD }

  public int getColumnCount() { //TBD } 

  public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) { //TBD }

  // Insert a value into model only if not exists yet

  public void insertData(String something) throws AlreadyExistsException {

      // Check if element already in model
      // Either throw exception or update model
      // Dont forget to call fireTableRowsInserted() !

  }
```

}

Comment: i haven't `AlreadyExistsException`! I have found a `AlreadyExistsException.java` code which contains more then 2k rows and i don't think i need this. I Think easiest way to accomplish this question is simply by getting every single row, split it and then check it! Simply i thought there is already built-in method! But i guess not;(

Comment: Sorry, the example was not intended to be an ready to copy and pastable example, rather a cooking recipe how to make a custom model for JTable. So "AlreadyExistsException" would be a custom exception class, but again this one example on how to indicate failure to insert duplicate data in the model. You are free to return a boolean, just ignore the duplicate or whatever best suits your usecase! And the example does not say much about how the model would store the data, perhaps an ArrayList of Something would be a good choice. (So even the method signature of insertData() is just an example...)

Answer (score 1):

Have accomplished my question like this!

```
private boolean isEntry(String name, String size) {
    int rowCount = jTable.getRowCount();
    String row = null, tname = null, tsize = null, input = name + "|" + size;
    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount - 1; i++) {
        tname = (String) jTable.getValueAt(i, 0);
        tsize = (String) jTable.getValueAt(i, 2);
        row = tname + "|" + tsize;
        if (input.equalsIgnoreCase(row)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Apart from being an ugly solution against all principles of using `JTable`s (and why the string concatenation?) this doesn't work with column arrangement. `getValueAt` delivers values from _view_ columns. When the user arranges columns into a different order the column numbers have to be translated.

Comment: ok, but in my case, no reordering or table editing is available!